# maker ldapjs use tls

Tags: node.js, ssl, ldap

Is it possible to make ldapjs (with nodejs) use TLS instead of just SSL ?

If yes, how would I set this ?

If no, are their any other ldap libraries for nodejs that support TLS ?

The only information I can find is
ldaps:// the latter would connect over SSL (note that this will not use the LDAP TLS extended operation, but literally an SSL connection to port 636, as in LDAP v2).

And on the homepage says
Doesn't support TLS extended operation (seriously, just use SSL)

Any suggestions on a solution if I'm **required** to use TLS to connect to the ldap server?

Comment: Do you mean `STARTTLS`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry still learning about ldap ,startTLS and SSL/TLS and got a bit mixed up. This helped http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200305/msg00084.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though it's an old question, I wanted to add the following answer:

```
var options = {
    'rejectUnauthorized': false, 
};

var client= ldap.createClient({
    url: 'ldap://127.0.0.1:389' 
    tlsOptions: options
});     

client.starttls(options,[], function(err) {
    console.log('inside the starttls callback');
    client.bind('cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com', 'admin',callback );
});
```